# c# - is it possible to use Castle.Facilities.NHibernate on .Net v3.5?

Tags: .net, nhibernate, inversion-of-control, castle-windsor, windsor-nhfacility

I'm developing an ASP.NET application using Windsor and NHibernate. I want to use Castle's new [NHibernateFacility](https://github.com/haf/Castle.Facilities.NHibernate/wiki) but I'm stuck on .NET 3.5 and NHibernateFacility along with AutoTx are targeted only to .NET 4.

Is it safe to recompile them on v3.5? If not, is there another easy way to maintain more than one ISessionFactory per application?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

the easiest way is `IDictionary<string, ISessionFactory>`. If the access is single threaded or all sessionfactories are initialised at startup then no synchronisation is needed.

Comment: I more interested in knowing if it is possible to use Castle.Facilities.NHibernate on .NET 3.5 because i'm also interested in using the AutoTx Facility

Comment: i can only guess but IMO no because it most certainly uses concurrent dictionaries which were introduced in .NET 4